# Splitting $d+1$ pairs in $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that the two convex hulls intersect.

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry, discrete-geometry

I am struggling with the following problem.

Given $d+1$ pairs of points $P_i=(x_i, y_i)\in \mathbb{R}^d\times \mathbb{R}^d$, $i=0,\ldots ,d$. Show that we can split the pairs $P_i$ into $u_i$ and $v_i$ such that their convex hulls $\rm{conv}(u_0,\ldots,u_d)\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ and $\rm{conv}(v_0,\ldots,v_d)\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ intersect.

I first thought that it could be somehow shown by using Tverberg or the Carathéodory's colorful Theorem, but I was not able to. Then I thought about proving it via contradiction. That is, assume that for any split the convex hulls do not intersect. Then pick a split for which the distance between the two convex hulls is minimal (it then is >0) and construct another split, which has a smaller distance and thus we obtain a contradiction. Unfortunately, that I couldn't work out either.

Comment: Hint: consider points that have the same “barycentric” coordinates in both convex hulls.

Comment: Hi Mindlack. Do you mean for the proof by contradiction, where I pick convex hulls with minimal (but non-zero) distance? It is not clear to me how this would help? Might be also just because I wasn't familiar yet with barycentric coordinates and had to read up.

Comment: Search for common points of the form $P=\sum_{i=0}^d{\lambda_iu_i}=\sum_{i=0}^d{\lambda_iv_i}$ (where the $\lambda_i$ are non-negative and add up to $1$).

Comment: mmh....I apparently don't seem to get your hint. Sorry, but I don't see how this helps. After all, I need to show that there is such a common point for an appropriate selection of the $u_i$.

Comment: Let’s try another, more explicit, hint, then: show there are signs $s_0,\ldots,s_d$ such that $0$ is a convex combination of $s_0(x_0-y_0),\ldots,s_d(x_d-y_d)$.

Comment: Thanks. I think I got it :)